# What is the single name for this thing?

Tags: single-word-requests, image-identification

It protects the people from falling from building.

[image]

Is there any single name for it?

Comment: What is the name for it in your language? Which dictionary have you looked up the translation in, and what did it say? (Hint: it's the exact same word in your language as it is in English.)

Answer (score 5):

It's a [Balustrade](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/balustrade) which means a row of balusters topped by a rail.

> Baluster : an object or vertical member (such as the leg of a table, a round in a chair back, or the stem of a glass) having a vaselike or turned outline;

[image]

Synonymns : Railing, fence, rails, banister, bars etc.

Answer (score 4):

It's a balustrade.

> 1 : a row of balusters topped by a rail 2 : a low parapet or barrier

[Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/balustrade)

[image: Balustrade]

Comment: You need to attribute the source of your quote.

Answer (score 3):

It's a **railing**:

> a barrier consisting of a rail and supports
>   <sub>[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/railing)</sub>

Pictures are probably more valuable here though. Searching for "balcony railing" will return many relevant images, including this one:

> [image]
>   <sub>Wikimedia Commons: [Prague Praha 2014 Holmstad Beautiful **railing** on balcony at Mala Strana](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Prague_Praha_2014_Holmstad_Beautiful_railing_on_balcony_at_Mala_Strana.JPG)</sub>